# Ayuda con extraer URL con php

Tags: php, url, curl, get

¿Cómo puedo extraer una url en especifico de un website?

Debido a que la url de esta web es dinámica me gustaria además de extraerla seguirla con php y convertirla en una url mía. Ejemplo:

Ver codigo interno y extraer url de video mp4 de: [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com)

Se puede obtener una url: [//www.instagram.com/video.mp4?lldFOXNwV0VsdWo0c3R2RExzVmhHTGxJTnNCYk10yOXJEOE9DVElKejVCc0dVQjdzV0pnaVFKcU1VdHhrNVM9MQ==](http:////www.instagram.com/video.mp4?lldFOXNwV0VsdWo0c3R2RExzVmhHTGxJTnNCYk10yOXJEOE9DVElKejVCc0dVQjdzV0pnaVFKcU1VdHhrNVM9MQ==)

como cambia cada cierto tiempo seguirla con php y crear una url personalizada con tu dominio ejemplo: [//midominio.com/id2?0012.mp4](http:////midominio.com/id2?0012.mp4)

He oido sobre preg_match - grab url - Regex

Comment: a ver si entendí bien tu quieres ver el video de una link y subirldo a tu base de datos asi como Youtube? yo tengo uno code pero se bien lo que quieres hacer si copiar y subir o la informacion

Comment: Seguir una URL remota que es dinamica como lo son la url de amazon s3 y  para evitar volver ah obtener la url de amazon dinamica seguirla con un codigo que este constantemente este verificando y que me entregue una url de siguimiento para publicarla en mi web si tener que preocuparme de volver ah actualizar. ejemplo //midominio.com/laurldinamica.mp4?id=44

Comment: tu quieres nada url asi como Youtube youtube.com/watch?v=BqDpLkNvZEs ahi un archivo para eso se llama alphaID.php

Comment: si pero el archivo seria remoto como un hotlink

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la urls de instagram, youtube, y muchas otras paginas cambian constantemente, y el quiere seguirlas, para no estar buscandolas y editando la bdd a cada rato

Comment: Exacto las url de los archivos multimedias, pero la web que quiero obtener el link del video esta en un iframe con:

Comment: <video class="jw-video jw-reset" disableremoteplayback="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" preload="none" jw-loaded="data" src="https://videos.drive.amazonaws.com/video/templink/5m9T1UtbxOz6xeQ_mhxtEBqm8mWIbsT2meVmSQqPalMeJxFPc?x-data=true" jw-played=""></video>

Comment: Mira yo intentaba hacer algo similar a lo que haces, yo lo qe hacia era en un nuevo archivo php, ponia un echo file_get_contents('iframe-url) eso lo ponia en el body dentro del html , y en el head ponia la etiqueta base a la url del dominio ( esto para que los scripts del iframe no contenga error de url), luego tenia un form con un input que enviaba los datos a id.php, entonces el valor del input lo extraia con javascript obteniendo el src del video y poniendoselo al input automaticamente y cuando el input tuviese un valor el formulario se enviaria automaticamente

Comment: Pero el problema venia a que justamente tenia que ejecutar esa nyeva pagina para tener los valores, no puedo usar include porque incluiria todo el archivo y por ende me mostraria todo el iframe y el documento, funcionaria si le dieras un display none al body, ahi si creo que funcionara ( me llego esa idea ahora mismo) pero como quiera la carga de la pagina seria lenta, bueno aun asi puedes intentarlo

Comment: Eso suena genial, me gustaria que compartieras el codigo si es posible :)

Comment: Eso ya es imposible, renuncie al codigo y los elimine, pero nose, me surgierom nuevas ideas, quizas intente de nuevo

Answer (score 2):

Claro que se puede solo tendria que codificar esa url en hexadecimal, base64, md5 o lo que sea para luego capturarla y enviarla a ese link, con php harias algo como esto,  **Ojo los links que usare y la codificacion de los mismos no es real** , la pagina se llama id.php, variable a rescatar url..

```
<?php 
    // id.php?url=ahjhgfdadk==
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = base64_decode($url);
    header('LOCATION:'.$url);
?>
```

con eso esta, pero para eso tendrias que tener el link absoluto del video **Ojo la codificacion de la url es opcional** es solo una guia, claro tambien despus tendrias que comprobar si existe esa variable para que no se pueda hacer directamente a la url de la pagina (tambien es opcional)

Answer (score 0):

Ejempo:  `$name = alphaID(microtime(true) * 10000);`

`$name` es para en nombre del post asi como yo lo uso mas el ID del user o la fecha con `Time();`
para evitra dos ID's iguales
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450

**Funcion alphaID**

```
function alphaID($in, $to_num = false, $pad_up = false, $pass_key = null)
{
    $out   =   '';
    $index = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $base  = strlen($index);

    if ($pass_key !== null) {
        // Although this function's purpose is to just make the
        // ID short - and not so much secure,
        // with this patch by Simon Franz (http://blog.snaky.org/)
        // you can optionally supply a password to make it harder
        // to calculate the corresponding numeric ID

        for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($index); $n++) {
            $i[] = substr($index, $n, 1);
        }

        $pass_hash = hash('sha256',$pass_key);
        $pass_hash = (strlen($pass_hash) < strlen($index) ? hash('sha512', $pass_key) : $pass_hash);

        for ($n = 0; $n < strlen($index); $n++) {
            $p[] =  substr($pass_hash, $n, 1);
        }

        array_multisort($p, SORT_DESC, $i);
        $index = implode($i);
    }

    if ($to_num) {
        // Digital number  <<--  alphabet letter code
        $len = strlen($in) - 1;

        for ($t = $len; $t >= 0; $t--) {
            $bcp = bcpow($base, $len - $t);
            $out = $out + strpos($index, substr($in, $t, 1)) * $bcp;
        }

        if (is_numeric($pad_up)) {
            $pad_up--;

            if ($pad_up > 0) {
                $out -= pow($base, $pad_up);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Digital number  -->>  alphabet letter code
        if (is_numeric($pad_up)) {
            $pad_up--;

            if ($pad_up > 0) {
                $in += pow($base, $pad_up);
            }
        }

        for ($t = ($in != 0 ? floor(log($in, $base)) : 0); $t >= 0; $t--) {
            $bcp = bcpow($base, $t);
            $a   = floor($in / $bcp) % $base;
            $out = $out . substr($index, $a, 1);
            $in  = $in - ($a * $bcp);
        }
    }

    return $out;
}
```

**Notas del file :**

> ```
> /**
>  * Translates a number to a short alhanumeric version
>  *
>  * Translated any number up to 9007199254740992
>  * to a shorter version in letters e.g.:
>  * 9007199254740989 --> PpQXn7COf
>  *
>  * specifiying the second argument true, it will
>  * translate back e.g.:
>  * PpQXn7COf --> 9007199254740989
>  *
>  * this function is based on any2dec && dec2any by
>  * fragmer[at]mail[dot]ru
>  * see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php#52450
>  *
>  * If you want the alphaID to be at least 3 letter long, use the
>  * $pad_up = 3 argument
>  *
>  * In most cases this is better than totally random ID generators
>  * because this can easily avoid duplicate ID's.
>  * For example if you correlate the alpha ID to an auto incrementing ID
>  * in your database, you're done.
>  *
>  * The reverse is done because it makes it slightly more cryptic,
>  * but it also makes it easier to spread lots of IDs in different
>  * directories on your filesystem. Example:
>  * $part1 = substr($alpha_id,0,1);
>  * $part2 = substr($alpha_id,1,1);
>  * $part3 = substr($alpha_id,2,strlen($alpha_id));
>  * $destindir = "/".$part1."/".$part2."/".$part3;
>  * // by reversing, directories are more evenly spread out. The
>  * // first 26 directories already occupy 26 main levels
>  *
>  * more info on limitation:
>  * - http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/165372
>  *
>  * if you really need this for bigger numbers you probably have to look
>  * at things like: http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.bc.php
>  * or: http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.gmp.php
>  * but I haven't really dugg into this. If you have more info on those
>  * matters feel free to leave a comment.
>  *
>  * The following code block can be utilized by PEAR's Testing_DocTest
>  * <code>
>  * // Input //
>  * $number_in = 2188847690240;
>  * $alpha_in  = "SpQXn7Cb";
>  *
>  * // Execute //
>  * $alpha_out  = alphaID($number_in, false, 8);
>  * $number_out = alphaID($alpha_in, true, 8);
>  *
>  * if ($number_in != $number_out) {
>  *     echo "Conversion failure, ".$alpha_in." returns ".$number_out." instead of the ";
>  *     echo "desired: ".$number_in."\n";
>  * }
>  * if ($alpha_in != $alpha_out) {
>  *     echo "Conversion failure, ".$number_in." returns ".$alpha_out." instead of the ";
>  *     echo "desired: ".$alpha_in."\n";
>  * }
>  *
>  * // Show //
>  * echo $number_out." => ".$alpha_out."\n";
>  * echo $alpha_in." => ".$number_out."\n";
>  * echo alphaID(238328, false)." => ".alphaID(alphaID(238328, false), true)."\n";
>  *
>  * // expects:
>  * // 2188847690240 => SpQXn7Cb
>  * // SpQXn7Cb => 2188847690240
>  * // aaab => 238328
>  *
>  * </code>
>  *
>  * @author    Kevin van Zonneveld <kevin@vanzonneveld.net>
>  * @author    Simon Franz
>  * @author    Deadfish
>  * @author  SK83RJOSH
>  * @copyright 2008 Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
>  * @license   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php New BSD Licence
>  * @version   SVN: Release: $Id: alphaID.inc.php 344 2009-06-10 17:43:59Z kevin $
>  * @link    http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/
>  *
>  * @param mixed   $in   String or long input to translate
>  * @param boolean $to_num  Reverses translation when true
>  * @param mixed   $pad_up  Number or boolean padds the result up to a specified length
>  * @param string  $pass_key Supplying a password makes it harder to calculate the original ID
>  *
>  * @return mixed string or long
>  */
> ```

Comment: si te funciono marcala como bien